# Is it possible to have iPhone sdk 4.0 & lower ones like 3.0,3.1.2, 3.1.3 together in the system

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to have iPhone sdk 4.0 & lower ones like 3.0,3.1.2, 3.1.3 together in the system. I had 3.0 to 3.2 earlier and then installed 4.0...But my lower sdks have vanished...now all i have is 3.1.3, 3.2 and 4.0? Is this normal, or did i screw up during installation?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, if you want to support older OS you have to set the iOS deployment target to the older you want to support.

Ex : If you want your app to run on iOS 3.0 to 4.0 you set the iOS deployment target to iOS 3.0.